# Quantifying the 'agreement' between the distribution of age in two populations

Tags: distributions, association-measure

I have a set of patients, of which a subset are 'enrolled' patients who were included into a study (the study population). For all the patients I have some limited data, including their age at the time of the study.

In order to demonstrate the characteristics of our study population and compare it with the whole population, I produced the following density plot:

[image]

I quite like this plot, however I would also like to quantify the level of 'agreement' between the two populations in terms of the distribution of age. What measure would be appropriate?

Comment: The simplest would be to use Chi^2 test. If you want to leave the data continious use Kolmogorov-Smirnov test.

Comment: And the graph is really nice!

Answer (score 1):

**Note**:you can't really "Quantify" the difference between two distributions because that would require evaluation of the difference in all the various parameters, moments, quantiles etc. Putting all that into one measure isn't possible.

**However** a test exists to determine whether an assumption of equal distribution should be rejected. That is the K-S test.

The non parametric Kolomogorov-smirnov test would work well here. It test for *any* differences in the distributions(***F(X)*** and ***F(Y)***) of any 2 random variables ***X*** and ***Y***.

**Step1: the hypotheses**

The null is
$$H_0: F(X) = G(Y)$$
and a general alternative hypothesis $$H_1: F(X) ≠ G(Y) $$

The test will depend on the *empirical distributions of the observed $X$ and $Y$*

**step 2: The test statistic**

the test statistic used is :
$$J=\frac{mn}{d} max_{i=1,2...N}(|F_m(Z_{(i )}) − G_n (Z_{(i )})|)$$
$where:$

$m$ is the sample size of $X$

$n$ is the sample size of $Y$

$d$ = **GCD** of $m$ and $n$

$N=n+m$

$Z_{(i)}$ is the combined **ordered** sample of $X$ and $Y$ and

$F_{t}(k)$ is the empirical distribution

As with all hypothesis test there is a critical value (based on a chosen significance level) which is denoted by $J_{\alpha}$ which can be obtained from the software used

**The decision rule**

The null is rejected if $J$ $>$ $J_{\alpha}$

**PS**

- When there are ties in the data the test statistic will need some adjustment

The reference book is Wiley's Series in Probability and Statistics: Non parametric statistics

Comment: This does'nt really answer the question. The OP asked for a *measurement* of the difference, not really for a test.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen..I've edited the answer to clarify why *quantifying the difference* isn't possible.

Comment: I don't agree that you can't quantify the difference. What you say (in the edits) amount to saying that you will not find one measurement which is good *for all purposes*, and that is clear.  But the OP only asks for a measurement for one purpose. The KS test statistic could be one such, there are many others.  What works depend on what is really the purpose of the OP.

Comment: Isn't the OP's purpose (*quantifying the difference between the age distributions*) already stated? And my answer such a measure isn't there.

Comment: What do you mean that "he asks for a measurement for one purpose?"

Comment: I suppose I was thinking about something more like the "goodness of fit" measures that you can use when fitting a straight line onto a graph. But this approach is also nice.

Comment: To clarify, the result of the Kolomogorov-smirnov test would effectively answer "how likely is it that this sample is not a random sampling of this population?"

Comment: @thomasfedb How  do you mean "not a random sampling". Isn't that already known through the method of data collection used

Comment: @thomasfedb could you also please post the "goodness of fit method you had in mind

Comment: @machazthegamer squared differences and all that fun. I like this solution, fits in well with how we handle other sorts of variables. Have to see if there's a good R package for it!